# Handlebars .hbt vs .hbs - what is the difference

Tags: handlebars.js

In some cases different tools using .hbt files (e.g. [metalsmith](https://github.com/metalsmith/metalsmith)) for handlebars, while i also find other tools (e.g. [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble/)) or examples where .hbs files are used.

Is there a difference between .hbt and .hbs files and if yes, what is the difference?